# Example of a proposition that is true when its quantifier ranges over integers, but false over rationals

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> I was asked to give an example of a proposition with a quantifier which is true if the quantifier ranges over the integers, but false if it ranges over the rational numbers.

My attempt:

$$(\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, 2n =n^2)$$

> Is this the correct approach?

Comment: If $(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}) P(x)$ is true, then so is $(\exists x \in \mathbb{Q}) P(x)$, as the same $x$ works for both.

Comment: In general, you'll want to look for propositions with universal rather than existential quantifiers.

Comment: This is my first mathematical reasoning class. Totally new to me. I'll try and work off of what you said to understand it a little more.

Comment: Ok what if I wrote then $(\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n^2\geq n)$ is that an appropriate answer to the question?

Comment: That works................

Comment: You could even do something extremely simple, like $(\forall x) x \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find an expression
that gives different values for integers
than non-integers.

An obvious candidate is
$\lfloor x \rfloor$,
the integer part of $x$.
This is $x$ when $x$ is an integer
and less than $x$ otherwise.

Therefore one proposition that works is
$P(x) \equiv (x = \lfloor x \rfloor)$.